# Ionic + Angular: Uncaught TypeError: app.controler is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I started working on an Ionic project and when I try to run this code I get this error:
app.js Uncaught TypeError: app.controler is not a function(anonymous function)
And I don't know if there's any difference between working with just angular and angular with ionic.

Thanks for your help in advance

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>    
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>  
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
<!-- <div class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
  <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
</div> -->
<div ng-controller="tasks" ng-repeat="t in task" style="margin-top:40px;">
    <ul class="list">
        <a href="trabalho.html"><li class="item">
        {{t}}
        </li></a>
    </ul>
</div>

<a href="index.html" class="button button-assertive">Sair</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
  // for form inputs)
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

  // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
  // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
  // a much nicer keyboard experience.
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
 });
});


app.controler('tasks',function($scope){
    $scope.task = ["Liveware","Casa","Inatel"];
});
```

Comment: i think u miss spelled the word controller please make it as controller instead of controler

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you